# Perl error message

Tags: perl

I am teaching myself Perl from a book, and have the following code fragment which produces an error message
`Argument "?M-\0M-^S10" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>) at ./Ch14.pl line 7.`

The result of the sort seems to be OK, and I can't seem to find the reason for the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @numbers = qw/17 1000 04 1.50 3.14159 –10 1.5 4 2001 90210 666/;

sub by_number { $a <=> $b }

my @sorted = sort by_number @numbers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `–` sign you have there is not a `-`, it's an EN DASH (U+2013). 
Delete and re-type it with the minus button on your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks - this fixed the problem. I would still like to understand the error message if possible

Comment: The error message is mangled because of some encoding problem somewhere. Since it's not the minus sign, that "–10" is treated as a string, and `<=>` only works on numbers.